# Which iPhones and iOS's are compatible with which Macs and MacOS's (and iTunes)?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ios, itunes

Current equipment:

- iPhone 6S with iOS 11.0.3
- MacBookPro9,1 2012 (MD104) with MacOS 10.9.5, iTunes 12.6.2.20

***Before you say anything, I still use the above laptop because of software for work that I must use that will not run on a newer MacOS.***

I'd like to upgrade my iPhone.  If I do, I understand that it will come with iOS 16 and downgrading is impossible.  I am not sure which version of iTunes and MacOS it will need.

I'm concerned that a new iPhone with a newer iOS will require a newer version of iTunes on my Mac, which will require a newer MacOS, which may require a newer MacBook altogether.

I'd like to avoid buying a new laptop and losing the ability to use my work software just because I want to upgrade my phone.

So the question is, is there a compatibility list/chart to show which iPhone/iOS works with which Mac/MacOS/iTunes?

***EDIT:  Given the comments I'll ask a more specific question:  If I upgrade my iPhone to iOS 15.7 (the option given), which iTunes will be required?  Which MacOS will be required for that version of iTunes?  Will my existing MacBook Pro be enough for that MacOS?  This is a specific case of what I'm asking above.***

Comment: I'm somewhat puzzled by an app that can run 10.9 & not still run all the way to 10.14. I can't think of any major blockers to that. 10.15 was a blocker for many things. Also, that iPhone is capable of running iOS 15. Anecdotally, devices here from the 5S to the 13 Pro Max work on both the last iTunes [Mojave] and latest Music [Monterey]. Haven't tested iOS16 yet.

Comment: So, any person who answers will need the same phone as yours and the same computer. If they have that why do you think they should run tests for you if they are happy with how their setup is working?

Comment: @SolarMike Perhaps someone used to have this or a similar configuration and can share what they did.  They don't need to do anything new, I'm only asking for they benefit of their experience.

Comment: I would start by finding out *for certain* what is the maximum OS this app can run on. That's the limiting factor & also the one no-one else can discover from the current information. You will find there are very very few people in the world with an OS that old & a brand new phone to link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple in the past has had excellent backwards support for your iPod, Watch, phone when they cease updating the os. If your device is incapable of running newer than iOS 15 you should have a very long run of current and future apps to sync with it. This is Apple first party expectations only. Third party depends entirely on the budget of that specific third party.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#Overview

Case in point, iOS 12 just got updates in August 2022. As long as you update each device as far as it can go, you can expect the longest coverage. If however you stopped on iOS 13 (for example when you could have gone to iOS 14 and then iOS 15), you will have much shorter windows of support and updates.

You’re in that tough spot with iOS 11. It will work for as long as it works, and you may or may not have luck going to 12.5.7 when the time comes.